# Generation of a 7 digit student number

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I just started with vb.net so please be patient with me here.

I'm working on an uni assignment where I need to build a small student registration program.

I need to create a 7 digit student number whenever a user clicks register, my code and validation and connection to DB is working fine, *Im just struggling with the generation of the student number*

**Instructions for generating student nr**

1. The student number should have 7 digits
2. The first two digits represent the year the student registers in (the last two digits of the full year) Which I get like this and it works fine: `Dim cyear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")`
3. **Here is my problem:** 
   the next 4 numbers represents the number of students who have registered thus far, this number is always padded with 0 from the left to make up four digits.

---

**Example**

if 20 students have registered thus far (in 2014) then the next student will
have student number 140021

---

4 The last digit is a check digit which you get by summing the first 6 individual numbers of the student number, divide the result by 10 and take the remainder, and subtract the remainder by 10 to get last digit. *Fine that is easy enough*, but what if only one student has registered thus far? Surely that cant produce a correct result

**My Question**

(See Number 3 above) How do I generate numbers 3 to 6, padding from left to right incrementing with one with each new registration?

I tried the following code but it is far off from working

```
'Generate Student NR'
Dim newstudent As Integer
'displays 1st 2 letter of current year for student number'
Dim cyear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")
Dim lastdigit As Double
Dim lastdigitRemainder
Dim studentnr As Integer
'if statment to generate new student number for each registration'
If (register.Enabled = True) Then
    newstudent = cyear + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1
    'generate last digit of student nr'
    lastdigit = (cyear + newstudent) / 10
    lastdigitRemainder = lastdigit - 10
    studentnr = lastdigit + lastdigitRemainder
    MsgBox(studentnr)
```

**My interface looks like this**

[image]

Please note Im not asking for someone to complete this code for me, im just looking for a bit of advice, someone who can point me in the right direction etc. Also is the IF statment the correct selection structure I should use for the generation of the student number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Dim intYear As Integer = TextBox1.Text 'The years last two digits'
  'Show the student id: pad the students number with 0's, works with single, double etc digits. The intStudents is the variable I used for the student totals.
  MessageBox.Show(CStr(intYear.ToString) & intStudents.ToString("0000"))
```

A little more perferred way...

```
  Dim strYear As String = TextBox1.Text
  MessageBox.Show(strYear & intStudents.ToString("D4")) 'D means the format and the number 4 is the length...
```

Your issue with your if that you have asked...

```
'I assume this is your register button... if so you can do this..
 If (register.Enabled) Then
  'whatever else you need
 End If
```

Heres you full edited code...

```
 'Generate Student NR'
 Dim newstudent As String
 Dim cyear As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")
 Dim studentTotal As Integer = 13 'However many students registered so far...
'if statment to generate new student number for each registration'
 If (register.Enabled = True) Then
   newstudent = cyear & studentTotal.ToString("D4") 
   MessageBox.Show(newstudent) 'Use this as "MsgBox" is depreciated in newer frameworks'
 End If
```

'Add one more to user variable...As you requested :)

```
 Dim studentTotal As Integer = 13 

 'Put in your click event ...
 studentTotal = studentTotal += 1
```

Comment: You can get rid of some variables as well; last digit and last digit remainder...

Comment: Yeah its working perfectly producing 140000, which is correct you are a live saver!!! just one question how do I increment by 1 with the above code whenever a registration takes place?

Comment: Easy.. Just use "+= 1"

Comment: Your welcome, I put it in the answer. If you have your Dims (your declarized variables in your click event) you will need to at least move the studenttotal one outside of the click event because everytime you click on it, this will be different. In order to maintain the count make it a private global variable in your class...

Comment: Everything works great the only problem Im having is regardless of how many registrations I do the newstudent variable does not increase and only stays at 140001 I added newstudet += 1 and studentotal +1 in my click event but it does not update the variables??

Comment: You need to put this variable outside your click event... Ex: Private intStudents As Integer (NOT inside the click event). Then IN the click event do this: intStudents = intStudents += 1

Answer (score 3):

This is how you pad numbers:

```
int number = 1;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("0000"));
```

VB

```
Dim number As Integer = 1
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("0000"))
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot! What happens if the last digit reaches 9 will it automatically go to next number?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  Should be as easy as writing a 2 line console app.  http://dotnetfiddle.net/tuDnWe

Comment: Thank you so much guys that really helped big time, just one more question if you dont mind, am I correct using an IF statment here?