# VB.NET 2010 count dataset to have an autogenerate ID

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("...")
Dim comm As New SqlCommand
Dim dread As SqlDataReader
```

I have a table named "tblStudents" and "StudID" as Primary Key.
I have a button and a textbox. I want to have an auto-generated Student ID in the textbox when I click the button with a format of "20140000001". If it's empty, it should display as "20140000000" Please help me with this. I really need it so much. I used to be a VB6 Programmer. VB.NET 2010 is a hell of a new environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you can use the `ToString` with how you want to format it...

For Example...

```
 .ToString(D8) 'Would produce 00000000, it would be 8 in length
 .ToString("00000000") 'This is another way. Say you have a year of 2014, it would be 20140000
```

Please see ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187329/generation-of-a-7-digit-student-number/22187577#22187577)*** post for a better understanding.